# Finding the exponent of a binary number written in scientific notation in MIPS

Tags: assembly, floating-point, mips, scientific-notation, exponent

Say I have the number 12 in decimal. This would be equal to 1100 in binary.
I know that this can be written as 1.100 * 2^3

How in MIPS can I get the exponent value 3 and store it in a register?

Comment: It's the bit position (indexing from 0) of first set bit. I don't think MIPS has separate assembly instruction to count that (x86 has), so you will probably have to scan from top most bit downward until you find bit set, or until you run out of bits. = That's for integers. For floating point it depends how your value is encoded in bits. The standard IEEE already does contain some exponent value, which would be maybe directly usable, or would need conversion.

Comment: @Ped7g That helped, i used the MIPS CLZ (count leading zeros) command and then subtracted that number from 31 to get the exponent.